# How can I replace hyphen "cells" in R data frames with zeros?

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr, lapply

I have a data frame with some positive numbers, some negative numbers, some words, and some hyphen "cells" in it, as such:

```
Revenue                 73.88   74.76    78.02   78.19  68.74
Other Revenue - Total   -       -        -       -       -
Total Revenue           73.88   74.76    78.02   78.19  68.74
Cost of Revenue - Total 21.09   21.61    23.01   22.76  19.99
Gross Profit            52.80    -53.15  -55.01  55.43  48.75
```

I want to replace the hyphens that are only found in the second to last columns with 0s, but only if the hyphens are not at the beginning of numbers.  For example, I don't want to turn a negative number positive.

I've tried:

```
df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], function(x) as.numeric(gsub("-", 0, x)))
```

but that returns the previous data frame as:

```
Revenue                 NA      NA       NA      NA     NA
Other Revenue - Total   0       0        0       0      0
Total Revenue           NA      NA       NA      NA     NA
Cost of Revenue - Total NA      NA       NA      NA     NA
Gross Profit            NA      NA       NA      NA     NA
```

which is something I definitely don't want.  How can I fix this?

Thanks.

This is the output when I call str():

```
str(income)
'data.frame':   49 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Items  : Factor w/ 49 levels "Accounting Change",..: 44 40 47 7 23 45 43 9 29 49 ...
 $ Recent1: Factor w/ 14 levels "-","0.00","11,305.00",..: 4 1 4 11 14 6 5 1 1 1 ...
 $ Recent2: Factor w/ 16 levels "-","-29.00","0.00",..: 5 1 5 15 16 9 6 1 1 2 ...
 $ Recent3: Factor w/ 17 levels "-","0.00","11,449.00",..: 5 1 5 15 17 10 6 1 1 4 ...
 $ Recent4: Factor w/ 18 levels "-","-31.00","0.00",..: 6 1 6 15 17 9 4 1 1 18 ...
 $ Recent5: Factor w/ 14 levels "-","0.00","1,617.00",..: 4 1 4 10 13 5 3 1 1 1 ...
```

Comment: Are those columns numeric?  I suspect they aren't?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention they are factors.

Comment: Why are they factors?  They don't look very much like factors to me.  Are they just auto-created-to-factors because your `read.csv` has `stringsasfactors` set?

Comment: Yes, they were automatically made into factors by read.xls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume it is named `dat`:

```
  dat[2:6] <- lapply( dat[2:6], function(col) as.numeric( gsub("-$|\\,", "", col) ) )
  dat[is.na(dat)] <- 0
```

Only replaces minus-signs at the end of a string, removes commas and the gsub coerces factors to character so you don't need to add `as.character`. When I imported your data using `read.fwf` and `textConnection` I got trailing spaces. You can either use gdata::trim to remove those first but this worked:

```
lapply(dat[2:6], function(col) as.numeric( gsub("-[ ]*$|\\,", "", col ) ) ) # on RHS 

 dat<-read.fwf(textConnection("Revenue                 73.88   74.76    78.02   78.19  68.74
 Other Revenue - Total   -       -        -       -       -
 Total Revenue           73.88   74.76    78.02   78.19  68.74
 Cost of Revenue - Total 21.09   21.61    23.01   22.76  19.99
 Gross Profit            52.80    -53.15  -55.01  55.43  48.75"), widths=c(24, rep(8,5)))

 dat[2:6] <- lapply( dat[2:6], function(col) as.numeric( gsub("-$|\\,", "", col) ) )
 dat[is.na(dat)] <- 0
 dat
#----------
                        V1    V2     V3     V4    V5    V6
1 Revenue                  73.88  74.76  78.02 78.19 68.74
2 Other Revenue - Total     0.00   0.00   0.00  0.00  0.00
3 Total Revenue            73.88  74.76  78.02 78.19 68.74
4 Cost of Revenue - Total  21.09  21.61  23.01 22.76 19.99
5 Gross Profit             52.80 -53.15 -55.01 55.43 48.75
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Joe hinted at, the values in a column of a `data.frame` have to be of the same type, so given that you have `-`s in the same vectors as what appear to be `numeric`s (52.80, 21.09, etc...), each column is being forced to type `character` (presumably). Try `gsub`bing with `"0"` instead of `0` and then converting the columns to `numeric`. Since you are forcing a `0` into a `character` column vector, it is coercing the rest of the vector elements to `NA`.

```
DF <- data.frame(
  X1=c(12,45,67,"-",9),
  X2=c(34,45,56,"-",12))
str(DF)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ X1: chr  "12" "45" "67" "-" ...
 $ X2: chr  "34" "45" "56" "-" ...
##
DF2 <- DF
DF2$X1 <- gsub("-","0",DF2$X1)
DF2$X1 <- as.numeric(DF2$X1)
str(DF2)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ X1: num  12 45 67 0 9
 $ X2: chr  "34" "45" "56" "-" ...
```

EDIT: To remove the commas in your values,

```
DF <- data.frame(
  X0=c("A","B","C","D"),
  X1=c("12,300.04","45.5","-","9,046.78"),
  X2=c("1,0001.12","33","-","12.6"))
for(j in 2:ncol(DF)){
  DF[,j] <- gsub(",","",as.character(DF[,j]))
  for(i in 1:nrow(DF)){
    if(nchar(DF[i,j])==1){
      DF[i,j] <- gsub("-","0",DF[i,j])
    } else {
      next
    }
  }
  DF[,j] <- as.numeric(DF[,j])
  DF[,j]
}
```

There are more efficient ways of doing this with `*apply` functions and regular expressions but this should work. I had to account for the fact that some of your values are negative so assuming the cells with only a `-` in them are only one character long, this should fix them without affecting the negative values in other cells.

Comment: I just tried this out and it didn't work.  It gave me the same results as last time, with the NAs.  My data frame was originally a data frame of factors, and even when I converted them to characters I still got the same results.

Comment: That's strange, I tried it with my example data above and did not get any NA values. Can you call `str()` on your data.frame and post the output please?

Comment: Ahh I think it is the commas in some of your values which were not shown initially. Let me tack some code on to the bottom of my answer so that I can have it formatted properly. Just a moment.